# Logrotate: Postrotate setfacl failed with no such file or directory error

Tags: squid, access-control-list, logrotate, setfacl

I set some extended ACL entries for `/var/log/squid3/` and `/var/log/squid3/access.log`.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:jetty:r-x,g:adm:r-x /var/log/squid3
sudo setfacl -m u:jetty:r--,g:adm:r-- /var/log/squid3/access.log
```

Because the log is under daily rotation I lose the acls every day.

I edit `sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/squid3` but it's not working.

```
running postrotate script
setfacl: /var/log/squid3/access.log: No such file or directory
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/squid3/*.log '
```

My squid3 logrotate fragment:

```
/var/log/squid3/*.log {
        daily
        compress
        delaycompress
        rotate 2
        missingok
        nocreate
        sharedscripts
        prerotate
                test ! -x /usr/sbin/sarg-reports || /usr/sbin/sarg-reports
        endscript
        postrotate
                test ! -e /var/run/squid3.pid || test ! -x /usr/sbin/squid3 || /usr/sbin/squid3 -k rotate
                /usr/bin/setfacl -m u:jetty:r--,g:adm:r-- /var/log/squid3/access.log
        endscript
}
```

A dry run of `sudo logrotate -vdf /etc/logrotate.d/squid3` gives:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/squid3

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/squid3/*.log  forced from command line (2 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/squid3/access.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/squid3/cache.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/squid3/access.log, log->rotateCount is 2
dateext suffix '-20140307'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.2.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.3.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.1.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.2.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.0.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.1.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 0), 
rotating log /var/log/squid3/cache.log, log->rotateCount is 2
dateext suffix '-20140307'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.2.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.3.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.2.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.0.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 0), 
running prerotate script
running script (multiple) with arg /var/log/squid3/*.log : "
        test ! -x /usr/sbin/sarg-reports || /usr/sbin/sarg-reports
"
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log to /var/log/squid3/access.log.1
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1
running postrotate script
running script (multiple) with arg /var/log/squid3/*.log : "
        test ! -e /var/run/squid3.pid || test ! -x /usr/sbin/squid3 || /usr/sbin/squid3 -k rotate
        /usr/bin/setfacl -m u:jetty:r--,g:adm:r-- /var/log/squid3/access.log
"
removing old log /var/log/squid3/access.log.3.gz
removing old log /var/log/squid3/cache.log.3.gz
```

A forced run gives an error:

```
sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/squid3 
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/squid3

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/squid3/*.log  forced from command line (2 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/squid3/access.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/squid3/cache.log
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/squid3/access.log, log->rotateCount is 2
dateext suffix '-20140307'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.2.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.3.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.1.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.2.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log.0.gz to /var/log/squid3/access.log.1.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/squid3/access.log.0.gz does not exist
rotating log /var/log/squid3/cache.log, log->rotateCount is 2
dateext suffix '-20140307'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.2.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.3.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 2), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.2.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 1), 
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log.0.gz to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1.gz (rotatecount 2, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/squid3/cache.log.0.gz does not exist
running prerotate script
renaming /var/log/squid3/access.log to /var/log/squid3/access.log.1
renaming /var/log/squid3/cache.log to /var/log/squid3/cache.log.1
running postrotate script
setfacl: /var/log/squid3/access.log: No such file or directory
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/squid3/*.log '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first guess would be that the `/var/log/squid3/access.log` file has not yet been re-created when the `setfacl` command gets executed.

To resolve that remove the `nocreate` in your logrotate configuration or replace it with a `create <mode> <owner> <group>` to have the logfile recreated before executing your postrotate command.

Comment: Yep! I replaced `nocreate` with `create 0640 proxy proxy` and it worked. Thank you.